# Custom Module to turn product page into homepage

Tags: product, module, magento-1, overrides, index

I have a "Today's Deal" product that changes automatically every 24 hours. It's the only product in the "Today's Deal" category.
I want the product page to be the homepage but i can't get the module to work. The controller reads the content of the category, gets the product ID and adds the ID to the URL but all i get is a blank page.

My **Teelegend_Overwritedefaulturl.xml (app/etc/modules)**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Teelegend_Overwritedefaulturl>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Cms/>
            </depends>
        </Teelegend_Overwritedefaulturl>
    </modules>
</config>
```

My **config.xml (app/code/local/Teelegend/Overwritedefaulturl/etc)**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Teelegend_Overwritedefaulturl>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Teelegend_Overwritedefaulturl>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <teelegend_overwritedefaulturl>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Teelegend_Overwritedefaulturl</module>
                    <frontName>teelegend_overwritedefaulturl</frontName>
                </args>
            </teelegend_overwritedefaulturl>
            <cms>
                <args>                    
                    <modules>
                        <Teelegend_Overwritedefaulturl before="Mage_Cms">Teelegend_Overwritedefaulturl</Teelegend_Overwritedefaulturl>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </cms>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

**My IndexController.php (app/code/local/Teelegend/Overwritedefaulturl/controllers)**

```
<?php
class Teelegend_Overwritedefaulturl_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction($coreRoute = null)
    {
        $categoryid = 3;
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryid);
        $collection = $category->getProductCollection()->setPageSize(1);
        $todaystee_id = $collection->getFirstItem()->getId();
        Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('catalog/product/view/id/' . $todaystee_id ));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declared your controller in wrong way. It should extend from cms index controller. This way Magento will not break up for all other cms pages.

```
<?php
require_once(Mage::getModuleDir('controllers','Mage_Cms').DS.'IndexController.php');

class Teelegend_Overwritedefaulturl_IndexController extends Mage_Cms_IndexController
{
    ...
}
```

To redirect you can try this.

```
$this->_redirect('catalog/product/view' , array('id'=> $todaystee_id));
```

Also I am not understanding why do you think this in complex way. In order to change your home page to this particular category, all you need to do this, go to your backend and edit `Home Page` from `CMS > Pages` and at the content side just put this code.

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="3" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

### EDIT

To redirect to different module's controller action, this is what you need to do.

```
 public function indexAction($coreRoute = null)
 {
    $categoryid = 3;
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryid);
    $collection = $category->getProductCollection()->setPageSize(1);
    $todaystee_id = $collection->getFirstItem()->getId();
    return $this->_forward('view', 'product', 'catalog', array('id' => $todaystee_id));
 }
```

This will work for sure. I tested it. The trick lies at `$this->_forward()` method. But in order to work this, you need to make sure that `$todaystee_id` holds a valid product id. Dont forget to clear the cache.

Comment: It still won't work.  
I don't want to change the homepage to this particular category, i want to change it to a particular product. Adding the block to my CMS page will list  the content of the directory, that's not what i need.

Comment: which one first or second ?

Comment: try second solution. by disabling this module. dont forget to clear the cache.

Comment: What is the second solution? Adding the block? Adding the block to my CMS page will list the content of the directory, that's not what i need. I want to show the product page.

Comment: All it needed was to add "cms" to Default Web URL in Configuration, to get it to work. But it's not working as planned, it's redirecting to the product page and changing the URL. 
When I open the homepage the URL changes to www.domain.com/catalog/product/view/id/3300 and i want it to be www.domain.com.
What can i use instead of redirect?

Comment: `$this->_forward()` is your friend insted of `$this->_redirect()`

Comment: When i change to `this->_forward('catalog/product/view/id/' . $todaystee_id);` i get a 404 Error.

Comment: please see my edit.